# Can anyone help me to understand the terms-'Toleration threshold' and 'Frustration threshold' in Dashboard report in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Can anyone help me to understand the terms-'Toleration threshold' and 'Frustration threshold' in Dashboard report in Jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9FuD.jpg)

Comment: any feedback on answer ? If ok you should accept it and upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

APDEX is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apdex)

To compute it JMeter needs 2 values:

- Satisfied count
- Tolerating count

Satisfied count is the Number of requests for which response time is lower than "**Toleration threshold**"
Tolerating count is the Number of requests for which response time is higher than **Toleration threshold** but lower than "**Frustration threshold**"

So JMeter let's you customize those 2 values as it depends on your SLR/SLA.

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.